# How can I install Postfix 2.10 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: apt, postfix

I have used "sudo apt-get install postfix" to install Postfix on my server, running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

However the version of Postfix that is installed in 2.9.3.

I looking for a feature that became available in Postfix 2.10 - the current stable release - however I don't seem to be able to get the version installed using the apt-get command.

Is there something that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your Postfix manually. 
Read the instructions on: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/server/postfix.html